# Shifting an array with less touches

Tags: javascript, array

I have an array that I am shifting by a certain number of spaces.  I am wondering if there is an better way to do the shift with less touches.  Here is my code

```
function rotate_array(array, shift){

    if(array.length -1 <= shift){
        shift %= array.length;
    }
    for(var i =0; i < shift; i++){
        var first = array[0];
        for(var j =0; j < array.length -1 ;j++){
            array[j] = array[j+1]
        }
        array[array.length - 1]  = first
    }
}

 var array = [4,2,1,3,5];
 rotate_array(array, 22);

  for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i])
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `concat` and `splice`..

```
shift %= array.length;
array = array.concat(array.splice(0,shift));
```

Or if you want the same array referance you can `shift` and `push`

```
for(i = 0; i < shift; i ++){
   var item = array.shift();
   array.push(item);
}
```

or shorten to

```
while((shift--) > 0){
   array.push(array.shift());
}
```